# Gulp: Target filenames which include certain match with gulp.src()

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm trying to set a gulp task that only applies to filenames which include a certain value in.

For example, i want the task to search for all files which include 'Directive' in them..

/dir/js/oneDirective.js  - YES

/dir/js/twoDirective.js  -  YES

/dir/js/file.js   - NO

How would you do this in Gulp using something like the following?

```
var SRC = 'app/shared/**/*(Directive).js';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the parenthesis it should already work. Try the following in your `gulp.src`:

```
'app/shared/**/*Directive.js'
```

Comment: This seems to work now for some reason.  I did try this to start with, but maybe there was an issue with my Gulp setup.  Thanks for the answer!